# Facebook api and java

Tags: java, facebook

Im playing around with the facebook api and java. Now i created a small application from a tutorial I saw, but when I cant compile it properly because netbeans underlines the lines:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams;

import com.google.code.facebookapi.Attachment;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.AttachmentMediaImage;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookJsonRestClient;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.FeedFacebookPhoto;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.Permission;
import com.google.code.facebookapi.TemplatizedAction;
```

How do i import these into netbeans to use?

Comment: add the jar files to netbeans so that it can find these classes.  I don't know the process (I use eclipse) but am pretty sure that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the facebook-java-api jar to your [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

Btw, I'm not sure whether the facebook-java-api project supports the new facebook API, a.k.a "the Graph API". You can take a look at [restfb](http://restfb.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the necessary jar files and add them as libraries in netbeans. You will find the apache commons library on the apache.org website and the other library is probably on the Google Code website.

---

Start by downloading the jar files and placing them in a location on your machine. Then in netbeans > project explorer right-click on the project Name >libraries tag and click Add Library. Then browse for the location of the jar files that you downloaded. Add each library this way.

Comment: thats what im also unsure of, which library to download and where from, apache just shows me the apache server

Comment: You are looking for the apache commons library. You can find it here: http://commons.apache.org/.

Comment: And the facebook api jar files can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/downloads/list